# Can you "resolve constants" in TOAD?

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

with pl/sql developer, you have the possibility to resolve constants.
It means replace the package constant in sql query by their value.

ex:

```
select my_package.my_constant from dual.
```

=>

```
select 2 /*my_package.my_constant*/ from dual.
```

But I haven't find a way to that in TOAD yet. Is it possible?

I know that I can use a wrapper instead of letting pl/sql developer modify my code. But the constants I'm using are not intended to be seen outside of my package. I only want to make a quick check of sql statement inside a package every now and then.

I know too that if I'm modifying my constant, the query generated won't give a correct value. As I said, I'm using that just to do a quick check from time to time

Comment: PL/SQL Developer lets you do that? I don't use that tool, but I'd expect it to return `ORA-06553: PLS-221: 'MY_CONSTANT' is not a procedure or is undefined` (as other tools I tested: SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD return).

Comment: If you try to execute the select my_package.my_constant from dual, it will do that. But with the tool resolve constant. PLSQL modify you code..

Comment: Are you saying that PL/SQL Developer GUI tool actually "creates" a wrapper function and returns the result? What a smart tool! Would you mind posting a screenshot of you executing that SELECT statement and the result? Not that I don't believe you, I'd just like to actually *see it*.

Comment: No It doesn't create a wrapper function. It comment the constant  and replace it by the value. If you change the value of the package constant, the generated query doesn't return the right value. Now In the company I work for use TOAD.  I can test what I'm saying to you about the way to find this tool. But you will find it in Option shortcut.

Comment: typing mistake last comment:  *can can't

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a PL/SQL package variable in an SQL scope (regardless of what client application you use to access the database). You would need to write a wrapper function and call that from SQL:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE constants_package IS
  SUBTYPE DECIBEL IS NUMBER(6,4);
  SUBTYPE NEWTON  IS NUMBER(12,2);

  MAX_DECIBELS CONSTANT DECIBEL := 99.9999;
  MAX_NEWTONS  CONSTANT NEWTON  := 9999999999.99;
  
  FUNCTION get_max_decibels RETURN DECIBEL;
  FUNCTION get_max_newtons  RETURN NEWTON;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY constants_package IS
  FUNCTION get_max_decibels RETURN DECIBEL
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN MAX_DECIBELS;
  END;

  FUNCTION get_max_newtons  RETURN NEWTON
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN MAX_NEWTONS;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT constants_package.max_decibels FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-06553: PLS-221: 'MAX_DECIBELS' is not a procedure or is undefined
> ```

But:

```sql
SELECT constants_package.get_max_decibels FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | GET_MAX_DECIBELS |
> | --- |
> | 99.9999 |

---

> I only want to make a quick check of sql statement inside a package every now and then.

Use PL/SQL (rather than SQL):

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(constants_package.max_decibels);
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 99.9999
> ```

---

> But the constant I'm using are not intended to be seen outside of my package.

If they are not public (i.e. they are defined in the package body) then you will not be able to access them outside the package. You would need to define a public function or procedure to access the private constant.

If they are public (i.e. they are defined in the package specification) then anything with `EXECUTE` permissions on the package will be able to read the value of the constants.

---

> I know too that if I'm modifying my constant, the query generated won't give a correct value. As I said, I'm using that just to do a quick check from time to time

You cannot modify a `CONSTANT`; they are constant. The closest you can get is if you recompile the package with a different value.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=84295034efa7b194ff9e542445c2ff8b)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've modified my question. I precise that what I'm searching is the tool from pl/sql developer and I precise why I want that instead of writting a wrapper.

Comment: @Pierre-olivierGendraud Then use PL/SQL Developer .... not every application supports the features of every other application and it appears that rewriting queries is a feature of PL/SQL Developer and not of Toad or SQL Developer (which the latter will pass the query to the database's SQL engine to parse rather than rewriting it on the client-side, which you appear to be stating that PL/SQL developer does). If you want to do something similar then use PL/SQL and `DBMS_OUTPUT` (see the edit to the question before your comment).

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing yet. (14.06.2022)

https://forums.toadworld.com/t/can-you-resolve-constants-in-toad/55444/3